# How to get the size of the original matrix (cv::Mat) from sub-array matrix?

Tags: opencv

I'll explain the question using an Opencv source code:

```
cv::Mat originalMat( 10, 10, CV_32FC2 );
cv::Mat subMat = originalMat(cv::Rect(0, 0, 5, 5)));
```

I'm trying to get the size of originaMat from subMat.
Functions & members that I found of cv::Mat as:
size, row, column
return only the data regarding subMat itself.
How can I get the size of originalMat from subMat?

It probably doesn't matter, but I'm using C++ language.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot. What is your purpose?

Comment: The purpose is forward the data from matrix to GPU with one copy transaction and then use only the data of the sub matrix. So i thought to send the GPU the size of the original matrix too.

Comment: An example case with code would be helpful. For now, I can say you can get the size with `originalMat.size()` anytime.

Comment: Whole source code is still in the design/implementation stage. I'm trying to be focused and ask a simple questions. The problem that i'll have only the reference to the sub matrix, so i cannot call size() from originalMat.

Comment: Make a class that extends cv::Mat and stores some additional values that you need.

Comment: thanks for you both, for now i just send the size of the original matrix together with a subMatrix